# Airflow DAG - Failed Task Doesn't Show Fail Status as It Should

Tags: airflow, webserver

I just started with Airflow DAG and encountered a strange issue with the tool. I am using airflow version 2.3.3 with SequentialExecutor.

**The script I Used:**

```
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

dag_args = {
    'owner': 'hao',
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
}

with DAG(
        dag_id='dependency_experiment',
        default_args=dag_args,
        description='experiment the dag task denpendency expression',
        start_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
        schedule_interval='@daily',
        dagrun_timeout=datetime.timedelta(seconds=10),
) as dag:

    pyOp = PythonOperator(
        task_id='pyOp',
        python_callable=lambda x: haha * x,
        op_kwargs={'x': 10}
    )

    pyOp
```

**The Log Snippit of This Task:**

> NameError: name 'haha' is not defined

> [2022-07-27, 18:19:34 EDT] {taskinstance.py:1415} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=dependency_experiment, task_id=pyOp, execution_date=20220728T021932, start_date=20220728T021934, end_date=20220728T021934

> [2022-07-27, 18:19:34 EDT] {standard_task_runner.py:92} ERROR - Failed to execute job 44 for task pyOp (name 'haha' is not defined; 19405)

> [2022-07-27, 18:19:34 EDT] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 1

> [2022-07-27, 18:19:34 EDT] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

**Problem:**
I purposefully defined a PythonOperator, which would fail. When I put the script on DAG, the task raised an exception as expected; however, the status for this task is always `skipped.` I cannot figure out why the task didn't show a `failed` status as expected. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are defining  `'retries'` and `'retry_delay'` in your dag_args dictionary.

[From the Docs:](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG)

> default_args (Optional[Dict]) – A dictionary of default parameters to be used as constructor keyword parameters when initialising operators. **Note that operators have the same hook, and precede those defined here**, meaning that if your dict contains ‘depends_on_past’: True here and ‘depends_on_past’: False in the operator’s call default_args, the actual value will be False.

When you set the  `'retries'`  to a value, Airflow thinks that the Task would be retried in an other time. So it shows it in UI as skipped.

If you delete `'retries'` and `'retry_delay'` from the `dag_args`, you'll see that task set to failed when you try to initiate the DAG.

---

When I ran your code in the logs I see:

```
INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=dependency_experiment, task_id=pyOp, execution_date=20220729T060953, start_date=20220729T060953, end_date=20220729T060953
```

After I delete the `'retries'` and `'retry_delay'` the same log becomes:

```
INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=dependency_experiment, task_id=pyOp, execution_date=20220729T061031, start_date=20220729T061031, end_date=20220729T061031
```

Comment: This is BRILLIANT! Thank you so much, I tested and the dag failed as expected. I do have a follow-up question that I hope you can help me with. Where should I find the documentation for what parameters can pass into`default_args`? I tried to search on Google, but no luck yet. Thank you so much @Sezai Burak Kantaci

Comment: You are welcome Vae, I'm glad you think this is helpful! Sadly I have not found a documentation on that. All my knowledge comes from different DAG script examples, about which parameters we can use in default args. Most diverse examples I've found are [this one from github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py) and [this one from documents](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/tutorial.html).

Comment: thank you so much! this is extremely helpful! I appreciate your help!